# Additional double quotes in CSV after changing n to r n

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv

I am well and truly stumped this morning. I have created a CSV file from data in a mysql database, and everything works fine. However, the problem comes when uploading the file as it has incorrect EOL; its using \n rather than \r\n.

I can open the file and change all the \n to \r\n fine, but when convert the string into an array its adds in double quotes where there shouldn't be any.

This is the original CSV

TH,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,5050085022119,5031151000019,5031151013286,20151118,20151118,20151118,,,0.00,GBP,0.00,0.00,0.00,"I-Read Ltd","GB 162 8111 28","TOYMASTER LIMITED",GB486083911,
TB,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,5031151013286,,"Kids Stuff Ltd, Putney","The Exchange","High Street",Putney,London,"SW15 1TW"
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,1,,,IR1,,"Around the World Sticker Book",6,1.5000,9.0000,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,2,,,B52,,"Playful Puppies poster sticker book",4,1.5000,6.0000,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,3,,,IR6,,"The Boys Brilliant Sticker Book",4,1.5000,6.0000,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,4,,,IR26,,"Themed Paint with Water On The Farm",1,1.5000,1.5000,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,5,,,IR36,,"Doodling and Colouring Dinosaur",1,1.0000,1.0000,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,6,,,IR4,,"On the Move Sticker Book",6,1.5000,9.0000,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,7,,,PW01,,"Paint with Water",2,0.9000,1.8000,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,8,,,IR30,,"Jumbo Sticker Book Princess Fun",3,1.0000,3.0000,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,9,,,30H,,"Activity Fun",3,0.5000,1.5000,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,10,,,IR27,,"Jumbo Sticker Book Pirate Fun",4,1.0000,4.0000,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,11,,,1006S,,"Big 1000 Fairy stickers pad",7,1.5000,10.5000,S,0.20
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,12,,,B56,,"Animals poster sticker book",2,1.5000,3.0000,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,13,,,IR2,,"Animals Around the World Sticker Book",9,1.5000,13.5000,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,14,,,IR3,,"In the City Sticker Book",6,1.5000,9.0000,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,15,,,IR5,,"The Girls Beautiful Sticker Book",10,1.5000,15.0000,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,16,,,B51,,"Horses and Ponies poster sticker book",7,1.5000,10.5000,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,17,,,IR28,,"Jumbo Sticker Book Fairy Funtime",7,1.0000,7.0000,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,18,,,B53,,"Cuddly Kittens poster sticker book",6,1.5000,9.0000,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,19,,,IR14,,"Glow in the Dark Dinosaur Kingdom",4,1.2500,5.0000,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,20,,,B57,,"Numbers poster sticker book",2,1.5000,3.0000,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,21,,,IR25,,"Themed Paint with Water Cuddly Pets",1,1.5000,1.5000,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,22,,,IR29,,"Jumbo Sticker Book Space Fun",3,1.0000,3.0000,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,23,,,B54,,"Farm poster sticker book",1,1.5000,1.5000,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,24,,,878H-S,,"Glow in the Dark Space Adventure",3,1.2500,3.7500,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,25,,,B50,,"Huggable Bunnies poster sticker book",1,1.5000,1.5000,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,26,,,32H,,"Dot to Dot Fun",4,0.5000,2.0000,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,27,,,877H-B,,"Ballerina Glitter Sticker book",2,1.2500,2.5000,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,28,,,31H,,"Colouring Fun",12,0.5000,6.0000,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,29,,,33H,,"Alphabet Dot to Dot",7,0.5000,3.5000,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,30,,,878H-A,,"Glow in the Dark Aliens and Monsters",10,1.2500,12.5000,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,31,,,878H-D,,"Glow in the Dark Dinosaur Kingdom",8,1.2500,10.0000,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,32,,,878H-U,,"Glow in the Dark Under the Sea",6,1.2500,7.5000,Z,0.00
TD,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,33,,,IR24,,"Themed Paint with Water Animal Fun",6,1.5000,9.0000,Z,0.00
TX,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,L,0.20,10.50,2.10,194.30
IT,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,192.55,10.50,2.10,194.30

and this is what is produced!

TH,1.00,550300,I,550300-app,5050085022119,5031151000019,5031151013286,20151118,20151118,20151118,,,0.00,GBP,0.00,0.00,0.00,"I-Read Ltd","GB 162 8111 28","TOYMASTER LIMITED",GB486083911,"
TB",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,5031151013286,,"Kids Stuff Ltd, Putney","The Exchange","High Street",Putney,London,"SW15 1TW
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,1,,,IR1,,"Around the World Sticker Book",6,1.5000,9.0000,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,2,,,B52,,"Playful Puppies poster sticker book",4,1.5000,6.0000,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,3,,,IR6,,"The Boys Brilliant Sticker Book",4,1.5000,6.0000,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,4,,,IR26,,"Themed Paint with Water On The Farm",1,1.5000,1.5000,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,5,,,IR36,,"Doodling and Colouring Dinosaur",1,1.0000,1.0000,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,6,,,IR4,,"On the Move Sticker Book",6,1.5000,9.0000,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,7,,,PW01,,"Paint with Water",2,0.9000,1.8000,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,8,,,IR30,,"Jumbo Sticker Book Princess Fun",3,1.0000,3.0000,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,9,,,30H,,"Activity Fun",3,0.5000,1.5000,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,10,,,IR27,,"Jumbo Sticker Book Pirate Fun",4,1.0000,4.0000,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,11,,,1006S,,"Big 1000 Fairy stickers pad",7,1.5000,10.5000,S,"0.20
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,12,,,B56,,"Animals poster sticker book",2,1.5000,3.0000,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,13,,,IR2,,"Animals Around the World Sticker Book",9,1.5000,13.5000,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,14,,,IR3,,"In the City Sticker Book",6,1.5000,9.0000,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,15,,,IR5,,"The Girls Beautiful Sticker Book",10,1.5000,15.0000,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,16,,,B51,,"Horses and Ponies poster sticker book",7,1.5000,10.5000,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,17,,,IR28,,"Jumbo Sticker Book Fairy Funtime",7,1.0000,7.0000,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,18,,,B53,,"Cuddly Kittens poster sticker book",6,1.5000,9.0000,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,19,,,IR14,,"Glow in the Dark Dinosaur Kingdom",4,1.2500,5.0000,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,20,,,B57,,"Numbers poster sticker book",2,1.5000,3.0000,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,21,,,IR25,,"Themed Paint with Water Cuddly Pets",1,1.5000,1.5000,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,22,,,IR29,,"Jumbo Sticker Book Space Fun",3,1.0000,3.0000,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,23,,,B54,,"Farm poster sticker book",1,1.5000,1.5000,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,24,,,878H-S,,"Glow in the Dark Space Adventure",3,1.2500,3.7500,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,25,,,B50,,"Huggable Bunnies poster sticker book",1,1.5000,1.5000,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,26,,,32H,,"Dot to Dot Fun",4,0.5000,2.0000,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,27,,,877H-B,,"Ballerina Glitter Sticker book",2,1.2500,2.5000,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,28,,,31H,,"Colouring Fun",12,0.5000,6.0000,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,29,,,33H,,"Alphabet Dot to Dot",7,0.5000,3.5000,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,30,,,878H-A,,"Glow in the Dark Aliens and Monsters",10,1.2500,12.5000,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,31,,,878H-D,,"Glow in the Dark Dinosaur Kingdom",8,1.2500,10.0000,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,32,,,878H-U,,"Glow in the Dark Under the Sea",6,1.2500,7.5000,Z,"0.00
TD",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,33,,,IR24,,"Themed Paint with Water Animal Fun",6,1.5000,9.0000,Z,"0.00
TX",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,L,0.20,10.50,2.10,"194.30
IT",1.00,550300,I,550300-app,192.55,10.50,2.10,194.30

(note the additional double quote at the end of the first column and at the beginning of the last column)

I have used the od command in mac to read the csv file and I can see that file has changed from \n to \r\n

This is the php I used. I have been hunting for an answer for hours and can not find anything relevant to this actual issue.

```
    $csvfile1 = __DIR__.'/csv/' . $jobid . '_tm.csv'; // FILE THAT HAS ALREADY BEEN CREATED
    $file_new = fopen ('csv/' . $jobid . '_tmnew.csv','w'); // CREATES NEW EMPTY CSV FILE
    $s_contents = file_get_contents($csvfile1); // READS THE CONTENTS OF THE EXISTING FILE
    $s_new = str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $s_contents); // REPLACES \N WITH \R\N
    $s_tidy = str_getcsv($s_new, ',' , '"', "#"); // CONVERTS STRING $s_new TO ARRAY
    fputcsv($file_new, $s_tidy); // PUTS THE ARRAY INTO THE NEW FILE
    fclose ($file_new); // SAVES THE FILE
```

Any light that can be thrown on this would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You do not use the variable `$s_new` after initializing it. So your replacement gets lost.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove all whitespaces before conversion to csv. Use this code for example or use a regular expression to remove the whitespaces from the string.

```
$s_new = str_replace(["\n"," "], ["\r\n", ""], $s_contents); // REPLACES \N WITH \R\N AND REMOVES WHITESPACES
```

This code works for me.

Sincerly

Comment: this should be a comment... Not answer.

Comment: I have put the info as a comment and put an answer here